# how to Sort and sum columns in datatable c# ,linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable like below

```
class  chapter  status  marks
A       II      FAIL    12  
A       II      PASS    76  
A       II      PASS    36  
A       III     PASS    54
A       III     FAIL    11  
A       III     PASS    99
```

i have to sum  this datatable with a String Array totalby {"class","chapter","status"} and
 write as html ouptut table with for loop in c# or linq

```
    class a SUMMARY
class  chapter  status  marks
A       II      PASS    76  
A       II      PASS    36  
        total   2       112
A       III     PASS    54
A       III     PASS    99
        total   2       153
    Sub total   4       265
A       II      FAIL    12  
A       III     FAIL    11
        total   2       23
    Sub total   2       23
    grand total 6       418
```

how to arrive this ?

Comment: So have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("class", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("chapter", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("marks", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", "II", "FAIL", 12});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", "II", "PASS", 76});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", "II", "PASS", 36});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", "III", "PASS", 54});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", "III", "FAIL", 11});  
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", "III", "PASS", 99});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { _class = x.Field<string>("class"), chapter = x.Field<string>("chapter"), status = x.Field<string>("status") }).ToList();
            int total = 0;
            int totalCount = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Class \t\tchapter\tstatus\tmarks");
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in group)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", row.Field<string>("class"), row.Field<string>("chapter"), row.Field<string>("status"),row.Field<int>("marks"));
                }
                int subtotal = group.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("marks"));
                int count = group.Count();
                Console.WriteLine("\tSub Total\t{0}\t{1}", count, subtotal);
                total += subtotal;
                totalCount += count;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\tGrand Total\t{0}\t{1}", totalCount, total);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Yes it works @jdweng , Since i mentioned String Array  is dynamic, it can be one or two columns how can i configure that ?